# How do I configure EF 4.1 to correctly model a non standard relationship

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following model which is unchangeable:

```
Person 
-------
int Id (PK)
int CompanyId
bool Deleted

Company
-------
int Id (PK)
int DefaultIdentifierId

Identifier
-------
int PersonId (PK)
int DefaultIdentifierId (PK)
string Identifier
```

I have created classes for each table but I'm struggling to specify the mappings to the database correctly. I need to be able to return the Id of a non deleted person given the company id and Identifer. In sql this would be a join between Company and Identifer via DefaultIdentifierId and a join between Person and Identifier via PersonId but I can't seem to get this specified correctly.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Anyway, the idea of *code-first* is that you create your *classes* first, and EF maps them easily to a new DB, using some conventions and your overrides. It's not well suited for mapping legacy DBs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't have navigation properties between `Company` and `Identifier` because neither `DefaultIdentifierId` in `Company` nor `DefaultIdentifierId` in `Identifier` are primary keys. (In `Identifier` it's only part of the key.) You can model a one-to-many relationship between `Company` and `Person` and between `Person` and `Identifier` though. So you could try these model classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DefaultIdentifierId { get; set; }
}

public class Identifier
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int DefaultIdentifierId { get; set; }
    public string IdentifierString { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Identifier> Identifiers { get; set; }
}
```

The **Id** in the name `DefaultIdentifierId` of `Company` is misleading. In this model this property is a simple scalar property and not a Foreign Key property which belongs to any navigation property.

To run the query you want you will have to use a `Join` in LINQ since you cannot navigate from `Company` to `Identifier` through navigation properties:

```
int companyId = 1;
string identifierString = "ABC";

List<int> personIds = context.Identifiers
    .Join(context.Companies,
          i => i.DefaultIdentifierId,
          c => c.DefaultIdentifierId,
          (i, c) => new { i, c })
    .Where(a => a.c.Id == companyId 
             && a.i.IdentifierString == identifierString
             && !a.i.Person.Deleted)
    .Select(a => a.i.Person.Id) // or a.i.PersonId should work as well
    .ToList();
```

The result is not necessarily unique but a list of Person Ids.